# Como resolver 'Erro: os componentes de runtime do JavaFX não foram encontrados' java 11 ( linux )

Tags: java, javafx

Eu baixei o Sdk do JavaFx para plataforma 11 do Java e estou tentando abrir meu FXML, porém quando eu tento executar o meu programar ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
  static String uId;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    // Código ...
    if (user.username == null){uId = null}
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
    URL fxml = getClass().getResource("./LG.fxml");
    Parent fxmlParent = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(fxml);
    arg0.setScene(new Scene(fxmlParent));
    arg0.setTitle("Tela de Login");
    if (uId == null) {
        System.out.println("Visualizando janela de Login");
        arg0.show();
    }else {

    }
}
```

"Erro: os componentes de runtime do JavaFX não foram encontrados. Eles são obrigatórios para executar este aplicativo"

Como eu resolvo e o que está causando isso?

Obs: estou usando o Eclipse IDE no Ubuntu 18.04 caso ajude :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um passo-a-passo do JavaFX para isso, e lá mostra quando esse erro ocorre e como resolver: ["Getting Started with JavaFX 12"](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) (no caso, está atualizado para a versão 12 do JavaFX, mas eu fiz o mesmo para  a versão 11 do JavaFX juntamente com o OpenJDK12 e funcionou).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como explicado no passo-a-passo do link, você precisa adicionar alguns *VM arguments* para a execução do projeto com JavaFX:

> --module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Substitua o `/path/to/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib` pelo caminho da biblioteca no seu computador.

Além disso, você já deve ter adicionado o JavaFX como uma biblioteca no projeto (isso é necessário a partir da versão 9 do Java), como explicado nesse passo-a-passo.

Recomendo você seguir (ou pelo menos estudar) esse passo-a-passo inteiro, mas a solução desse problema para o Eclipse está no item do menu lateral `JavaFX and Eclipse`.

<sup>Observação: pra mim parece desnecessário instalar a extensão *Java 12 Support for Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)* que o passo-a-passo sugere instalar (além de ela ainda estar em Beta, [o que vi que ela faz é simplesmente permitir testar um ou mais recursos experimentais no Java12](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java12/Examples)), eu não instalei; e a instalação da extensão *E(fx)clipse* é opcional.</sup>